# How to start EXE on a server in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have the c:\Program Files\Myexe.exe on the Server1
I run BIDS package on MyPC1 and can't start it.
On the server in the task manager I see the process started, but it hangs, possibly because of the security warning.

Thank you,

Nikolz

Comment: I don't know why it hangs, it runs by itself without any user intervention. It doesn't talk to the user. My guess is it is security warning or something. I don't know how to test it

Answer (score 0):

If you see the program start, then you have successfully started it!

You now need to find out why it hangs. What security warning are you referring to?

Does the program have a UI? If so, it won't work very well if started remotely - which user do you want it to talk to?